Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии менялся фон
Я хочу сделать так чтобы при нажатии менялся фон-типо был белый фон,нажал и он стал темным.

На кнопку иммею ввиду,забыл написать

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

тут чуть больше, но как раз про смену фона по нажатию на кнопку ну или вот


сделать так чтобы при нажатии менялся фон-типо был белый фон,нажал и он стал темным

Такое можно сделать вот так...


document.querySelector('button').addEventListener(
  'click', 
  _ => document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('off')
)
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fff;
}
body.off {
  background-color: silver;
}
<button>Нажми меня</button>



